# Confusion regarding Image compression algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, image-processing

I had been reading a webpage on [Image Compression (Lossy and Non-lossy)](http://www.mikety.net/Articles/ImageComp/ImageComp.html).

Now this is my problem, I was successful in making a project on Face detection using opencv - however - my Project Guide is not satisfied - my project simply captures the frames from a Capture device [ webcam ] and passes frames in a function to detect the Faces in those frames and outputs the detect frames in Windows.

My Project Guide wants me to implement some algorithm either of image compression or morphing , etc. but was not happy on seeing such heavy usage of the Library -

So what I would like to know - is it possible to code using C or C++ - image compression algorithms? If yes would not the code size be huge? (my project is supposed to be a minor one)

Please help me out, suppose I want to use the RLE compression using C++ how should I go about it?

Comment: "Is it possible to code using C or C++ -image compression algorithms". Uhm, yes. What do you think the image compression libraries are written in>

Comment: How much does one need to know about File formats like BMP, JPG etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to invent your own image compression or implement one of the standard ones?
( I assume this is for some sort of class/assignment, you wouldn't do this in the real world!)

You can compress simple images a little using something like Run-Length, especially if you can reduce the number of colours ie. a cartoon or graphic, but for a real photo style image it isn't going to work - that's why complex lossy techniques like jpeg or wavelets were invented.

Comment: How much does one need to know about File formats like BMP, JPG etc –

Comment: BMP is trivial, JPEG is complicated - the theory is relatively simple if you know the maths of FFT but the format is complicated

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible, and RLE compression is quite easy.  If you want to look at a relatively straight-forward approach to RLE that won't use a lot of code, look at implementing a version of [packbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits).

Here's another link as well: http://michael.dipperstein.com/rle/index.html (includes an implementation with source-code for both traditional RLE and packbits)

BTW, keep in mind that you could, with noisy data, actually end up with *more* data than uncompressed using RLE schemes.  For most "real-world" images though that have some form of low-pass filtering applied and a relatively good signal-to-noise ration (i.e,. above 40db), you should expect around 1.5:1 to 1.7:1 compression ratios.

Another option for lossless compression would be huffman-encoding ... that algorithm is more tolerant of noisy images, in that it generally prevents the data-expansion that could occur with those types of images when encoded with a RLE compression algorithm.

Finally, you didn't mention whether you were working with color or grayscale images ... if it's a color image, remember that you will find much greater redundancy if you compress each color-channel in a planar-color-channel image, rather than trying to compress contiguous RGB data.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a compression based on colour reduction with a space-filling-curve or a spatial index. A si reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity and it looks like a quadtree and a bit like a fractal. You want to look for Nick's hilbert curve quadtree spatial index blog!

Here is another interesting RLE encoding idea: [Lossless hierarchical run length encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874250/lossless-hierarchical-run-length-encoding). Maybe that's something for you?

Answer (score 0):

RLE is the best way to go here. Even the "simplest" compression algorithms are non-trivial and require in-depth knowledge of color space transforms, discrete sin/cosine transforms, entropy, etc.

Back to RLE... to loop  through pixesls use something like this:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lenna.png");
for(int i=0; i < img.rows; i++)
    for(int j=0; i < img.cols; j++)
        // You can now access the pixel value with cv::Vec3b
        std::cout << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << " " << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] << " " << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] << std::endl;
```

Count the number of similar pixels in a row and store them in any data structure (maybe a `< #Occurences, Vec3b >` tuple in a `vector`?). Once you have your final `vector`, don't forget to store the size of your image somewhere with the aforementioned `vector` (maybe in a simple `compressedImage` struct) and voilà, you just compressed an image. To store it in a file, I suggest you use `boost::serialize` or something similar.

Your final struct may look something similar to:

```
struct compressedImage {
  int height;
  int width;
  vector< pair<int, Vec3b> > data;
};
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

if you need to abstract the raster type, you can use GDAL C++ library. Here is the list of supported by default or on request raster formats:

http://gdal.org/formats_list.html